# Reset form without losing default value of dropdown in angular

Tags: javascript, angular

When I submit the form save all value in formData array and **reset** the form but **not see the default value of dropdown** it also reset(not work default value of dropdown value).

When running the first time run perfectly but submit any value then not set a default value. Use Template Driven form. What I do?

```
@Component({
  selector: "app-root",
  templateUrl: "./app.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./app.component.css"],
})
export class AppComponent {
  default = "advance";
  formData: { email: string; profesonal: string; password: string }[] = [];

  saveData(f) {
    this.formData.push(f.value);
    f.reset();
  }
}

HTML.......
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-10 col-md-8 col-sm-offset-1 col-md-offset-2">
      <form (ngSubmit)="saveData(f)" #f="ngForm">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="email">Email address</label>
          <input
            type="email"
            class="form-control"
            id="email"
            email
            required
            ngModel
            name="email"
            #email="ngModel"
            placeholder="Enter email"
          />
          <small
            id="emailHelp"
            class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="!email.valid && email.touched"
            >Please enter email</small
          >
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="profesonal">Example select</label>
          <select
            class="form-control"
            id="profesonal"
            [ngModel]="default"
            #profesonal="ngModel"
            name="profesonal"
          >
            <option value="basic">Basic</option>
            <option value="advance">Advanced</option>
            <option value="pro">Pro</option>
          </select>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="password">Password</label>
          <input
            type="password"
            class="form-control"
            id="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            required
            name="password"
            #password="ngModel"
            ngModel
          />
          <small
            id="emailHelp"
            class="text-danger"
            *ngIf="!password.valid && password.touched"
            >please enter password</small
          >
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="!f.valid">
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-12">
        <table class="table table-striped table-bordered">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th scope="col">Email</th>
              <th scope="col">Password</th>
              <th scope="col">Profesnal</th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr *ngFor="let f of formData">
              <td>{{ f.email }}</td>
              <td>{{ f.password }}</td>
              <td>{{ f.profesonal }}</td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Share the code where you are setting it initially.

Comment: Basically you will need to set it again after doing the reset.

Comment: by default value you mean a value from the options list or a placeholder? if it's a value from the options list, you just need to set it again after each reset, there is no running from that.

Comment: Hello,@vald Katz default value of the dropdown option also reset when submit the form

Comment: I hope i'm not wrong when i'm saying it, but form controls don't have a default value, they have a initial value that you init when creating the form.